# How to read integers separated by space from a file in php

Tags: php

I am trying to read a line where multiple numbers were separated by space using php. Initially I tried using fscanf however the issue is, as fscanf read one line at a time, it only reads the first number. I am confused what to do.

Sample Input 
20 30 -5987 456 523

Answer (score 8):

The best approach for this case is to use a combination of explode and file reading. The strategy is initially read the whole line as an string. Then use explode to store the all the number in an array. However in that case the array would a string array later on we can change the type of array element from String to integer. Here is how

```
<?php
$_fp = fopen("php://stdin", "r");
fscanf($_fp, "%d\n", $count);
$numbers = explode(" ", trim(fgets($_fp)));
foreach ($numbers as &$number)
{
    $number = intval($number);
}
sort($numbers);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$input = trim(fgets(STDIN));
$arr = explode(" ", $input);      
foreach($arr as &$number){
    $number = (int)$number;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to eliminate white space from "fopen" function user "trim" function or surround variable with trim function.
Example :

```
echo "Please enter series limit : ";
$handles = fopen ("php://stdin","r");
$n = trim(fgets($handles));
```

So here we can remove white space in between the characters as well as at the end.